# Why does this mod_rewrite directive not work?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Due to a server migration, I'm attempting to direct all URI's starting with `/rc`, `/roundcube`, `/sm`, or `/squirrelmail` to `https://webmail.{HTTP_HOST}` using the following mod_rewrite code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(rc|roundcube|sm|squirrelmail)(\/)?(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://webmail.%1 [R=302, L]
```

Because I want this redirection to affect all virtual hosts on the machine, I'm putting it in the virtual host directive inside the httpd.conf file of Apache.

The server does have mod_rewrite enabled, but this above seems to do nothing at all!

Perhaps someone can spot my error?

An example of the intended result is:

http://www.mydomain.com/rc --> https://webmail.mydomain.com

It should be able to handle the task with or without the `www` or the trailing `/` and maybe parameters included when users bookmarked the original URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you simply put that in the **httpd.conf** file, there is no context for the rule. Try wrapping it in a location or directory (location probably better):

```
<Location "/">
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(rc|roundcube|sm|squirrelmail)(/)?(.*)?$
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://webmail.%2 [R=302,L]
</Location>
```

and get rid of the space after `R=302,`

Comment: Good show Jon, it was the space that was the show stopper although not quite there yet, I'm now getting `Firefox can't find the server at webmail.rc.`

Comment: @PeterSnow Ah! The conditions need to be in a different order and the backreference needs to be `%2`

Comment: You're a gentleman and scholar. Thank you Jon. It's perfect now.